Does the growler check also shorts to the armature metal body?

As much as i know,the growler is a tool that is used to find shorts between armature winding.
My question is:
Can it only find shorts between the windings themself or it can also find shorts between the winding and the metal body?(when using the hacksaw blade).

A growler is a tester that is basically like the primary of a transformer.  If you bring a shorted armature coil near the growler, it will induce a current into the armature coil causing the "feeler" which is often a hacksaw blade to vibrate, signaling the short when near the shorted section.
A growler relies on a short that would allow current to flow in a closed path, generating a magnetic field that can be felt by the "feeler".
So, a single-point short from the winding to the case/body would not allow current to flow in a closed path, and the "feeler" wouldn't vibrate due to the induced magnetic field.
If a winding shorted to the body in two places you could get current flow and a detectible field.

"...if a winding shorted to the body in two places you could get current flow and a detectible field."in that case,can it be detectible by the hacksaw blade in the regular testing procedure or i need to put the hacksaw in a different angle on the armature?

@Dan It's hard to guarantee that it would always be detectible.  It would depend on the location and loop area of the short circuit, and how close you could get the hacksaw blade.  So you might be able to detect it, but there's no guarantee.
